# Displaying the first five rows of the new data set having displayed all NaN rows in a column using .isnull in pandas

Tags: pandas, head, isnull

I have got a weather data set which I stripped to only find those rows in a column showing an NaN value using .isnull. I'd like to show the first five rows of this new data set using .head, but the system shows the first five rows of the whole table (even those with a value in). How can I work with this newly created data set displaying the first five rows of those rows showing NaN as a value? At first I gave the excel table the name "london" using london = read_csv('London_2014.csv'). Then I used the code london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull() to show only the values "NaN" for the column "Max Gust SpeedKm/h. 
When I try to rename the newly created dataset as follows: 
londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()] and then try
londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].head()] the system threw me the following error:
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) in 1 londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()]----> 2 londonNew[londonNew['Max GustSpeedKm/h'].head()]/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distpackages/pandas/core/frame.py in **getitem**(sel f, key)2804 if is_iterator(key)2805 key = list(key)-> 2806 indexer =self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]2807 2808 # take(does not accept boolean indexers/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing) – 1551 1552 self._validate_read_indexer(-> 1553 keyarr, indexer,o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing1554 )1555 return keyarr, indexer/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in_validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)1638 if missing == len(indexer):1639 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis-> 1640 raiseKeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")1641 1642 # We (temporarily)allow for some missing keys with .loc, except inKeyError: "None of[Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]" –

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks for your help!
Inga

Comment: Can you post some sample data+code so we can see exactly what it is you are trying to do, and what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Bertil, many thanks for coming back to me. I have got a table with weather data. In the column "Max Gust SpeedKm/h" I have got some values that are "NaN" and I have filtered them so that I only see those rows that contain "NaN" using the code: london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull(). I wanted to work with this new dataset in order to only display the first 5 rows of this new dataset where all the values for "Max Gust SpeedKm/h" are "NaN". But when I enter: london[london.head()] I get the first five rows of the original dataset. How can I create a new dataset out of the filtered data?

Comment: Is it possible to attach screenshots or excel sheets here? Then I could send you the file I'm reffering too. Sorry, I'm new to the site. I'm currently doing a Python Coding Course and this task has done my head in for days now. So you're help is very much appreciated! :-)

Comment: You need toprovide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in text form, not as a picture. Edit your question to display this, as well as the whole bit of code that relates to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all that is happening is that you are forgetting to assign the new view to a variable. Try this:

```
new_london = london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()]
new_london.head()
```

Or if you want to change the `london` dataframe to only work with this new data:

```
london = london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()]
london.head()
```

Comment: Thanks Bertil! I tried that and it comes back with a name error: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-292161984840> in <module>
----> 1 new_london=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()]
      2 new_london.head()
NameError: name 'london' is not defined

Comment: This means you don’t have a data frame variable called London like your comment indicated.

Comment: Thanks Bertil. That's very strange! In the very beginning of my research I've used london = read_csv('London_2014.csv') to name my excel table "london". Since then I've carried out all my coding using "london" as the name and it worked. Do you have any other idea I could try?

Comment: I also tried to name the new database "londonNew" and write the code as follows londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()] and then londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].head()], but that throws me the following error:

Comment: KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-338f0b8a3d4f> in <module>
      1 londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()]
----> 2 londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].head()]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2804             if is_iterator(key):
   2805                 key = list(key)

Comment: -> 2806             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2807 
   2808         # take() does not accept boolean indexers
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1551 
   1552         self._validate_read_indexer(
-> 1553             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
   1554         )

Comment: 1555         return keyarr, indexer
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1638             if missing == len(indexer):
   1639                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1640                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1641 
   1642             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([66.0, 50.0, 69.0, 39.0, nan], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"  I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Just tried with this londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()]
londonNew[londonNew['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].head()] I realised I hadn't used londonNew after renaming the dataset, but it still throws me a key error!

Comment: KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-281-3e8749fd3f44> in <module>1 londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull()]----> 2 londonNew[londonNew['Max GustSpeedKm/h'].head()]/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distpackages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(sel f, key)2804 if is_iterator(key)2805 key = list(key)-> 2806 indexer =self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]2807 2808 # take(does not accept boolean indexers/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)

Comment: 1551 1552 self._validate_read_indexer(-> 1553 keyarr, indexer,o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing1554 )1555 return keyarr, indexer/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in_validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)1638 if missing == len(indexer):1639 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis-> 1640 raiseKeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")1641 1642 # We (temporarily)allow for some missing keys with .loc, except inKeyError: "None of[Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Sorry I still had to do it in two halves as I can't make the code any shorter without deleting any actual words/numbers from it. I don't know what is and isn't important to you. Sorry!

Comment: No, you should *edit your original question* with the code you have written, and not just the traceback.

Comment: Sorry Bertil, I looked at what I entered again and have managed to resolve it now. The problem was the second line of code which I had written as londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].head()] instead of londonNew.head(). I assume if I just wanted to display the column "Max Gust SpeedKm/h" in a new table I would need to write londonNew=london[london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h']] and take it from there. Thank you so so much for your help. I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm just learning how to code and am so grateful for the help of an expert.

Comment: Great! If I answered your question, you can click the gray checkmark on the left side of this answer to mark it as accepted :-)